# Qt/QML: std::vector<int> handling

Tags: qt, qml, qobject

**Edit:** problem was with 5.6 only, which has a reduced set of supported "native" types according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html vs the latest version ...

According to this page: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html, `std::vector<int>` is suppported by QML if registered with `qRegisterMetaType()` and exposed/accessed as a property. However, I cannot get this to work.

My class (which can be instantiated by QML, so this level works) has declarations like:

```
// prop decl
Q_PROPERTY(std::vector<int> myVector READ myVector NOTIFY myVectorChanged)
// read accessor
Q_INVOKABLE std::vector<int> recordTime() const;
// signal (in signal section)
void myVectorChanged();
```

Registration via

```
qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<int> >("std::vector<int>");
```

When I push something into the vector and try accessing myVector.length or myVector.size, it returns 'undefined' (size() is not callable). How do I iterate over the elements? The page linked above says "Certain C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML to behave like JavaScript Array types" (and mentions `std::vector<int>` in the list), so I expected `length` and index access to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says this container will be converted to a JS array automatically. You don't need to register anything.

Of course, the conversion will be a copy, so modifying it will not modify the original array, and the way you use that is the same way you use a regular JS array. It definitely should have a `length` (not `length()`) property and support index access via `[]`.

Update:

After your stories of failure I decided to actually run a simple test:

```
class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    std::vector<int> test() { return std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; }
};

// in main.cpp
qmlRegisterType<Test>("Core", 1, 0, "Test"); 

  // in qml
  Test {
    Component.onCompleted: {
      var t = test()
      console.log(t.length, t) // qml: 7 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    }
  }
```

As you can see, it gives the expected output, no need to register anything whatsoever.

IIRC there was a problem with Qt that for some reason caused those automatic conversions to **not** kick in when you use a `Q_PROPERTY` interface. I suppose that issue is still valid, the solution thankfully is to simply not use a property but a simple return value.

If your problems persist, I suggest to carefully examine your code, or if necessary, clean and rebuild your project, because the conversion is definitely working out as expected, aside from the property related issue.

Comment: Not registering the std::vector<int> as metatype yields "QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'std::vector<int>' for property 'MyModel::myVector'" (so it fails one step earlier?).

Comment: I haven't actually used `std::vector`, only `QVector` and it didn't require registration. But maybe Qt already provides that for `QVector` and not for `vector`.

Comment: Also.. try just `qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<int>>()`

Comment: Nope, registering with qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<int>>() has same effect as not registering at all (using QVector<int> works without registration, but does not expose length, either).

Comment: Even switching everything to QVector<int> instead of std::vector<int> exposes the same behavior (length being undefined).

Comment: Hm, it seems the type is "QVariant(QVector<int>)" ... doesn't help me in any way, though.

Comment: Ah, I should have read the docs for my old Qt version: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html (which lacks all of the good stuff). Thank you!

Comment: You should specify if you are using such older version next time you ask a question ;)